# Algorithm for selecting a range of number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like your code suggestion for this algo.

Imagine you have an array of number 0 to 9.

In console you need to print always a set of 4 number, starting from 0.

so for example first set would be

0 - 1 - 2 - 3

when an event occurs occurs you need to print the next number and remove one from the pile

1 - 2 - 3 - 4

when an event occurs occurs you need do the same

2 - 3 - 4 - 5

and so on till you display the last number like

6 - 7 - 8 - 9

what is most elegant and faster way to implement this in JavaScript?

Without affecting the original array.

Solutions

```
var range = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var start = -1;

function get4()
{
    start++;
    if(start < 7 ) {

        return range.slice(start,start+4);
    }

}


console.log(get4());
console.log(get4());
console.log(get4());
console.log(get4());
console.log(get4()); 
console.log(get4());  
console.log(get4());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var range = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var start = -1;

function get4()
{
    start++;
    return range.slice(start,start+4);
}

console.log(get4()); //[0, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(get4()); //[1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(get4().join(' - ')); //2 - 3 - 4 - 5  (use join if you want them formatted as a string)

console.log(range); //[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] (is still intact)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fslice):

```
var start = 0;
var newArr = arr.slice(start, start + 4);
```

Comment: is slice effecting the original array?

Comment: @GibboK As per MDN link: `slice does not alter the original array, but returns a new "one level deep" copy that contains copies of the elements sliced from the original array.`